# How to Multi-Head learning

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I have about 5 models that work pretty well trained individually but I want to fuse them together in order to have one big model.
I'm looking into it because one big model is more easy to update (in production) than many small model 
this is an image of what I want to achieve.
[image]

my question are, is it ok to do it like this ?
having one dataset per head model, how am I supposed to train the whole model ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my question are, is it ok to do it like this

Sure you can do that. This approach is called [multi-task learning](https://ruder.io/multi-task/). Depending on your datasets and what you are trying to do, it will maybe even increase the performance. Microsoft used a [multi-task model](https://github.com/namisan/mt-dnn) to achieve some good results for the NLP Glue benchmark, but they also noted that you can increase the performance further by finetuning the joint model for each individual task.

> having one dataset per head model, how am I supposed to train the whole model?

All you need is pytorch [ModuleList](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#modulelist):

```py
#please note this is just pseudocode and I'm not well versed with computer vision
#therefore you need to check if resnet50 import is correct and look 
#for the imports of the task specific stuff
from torch import nn
from torchvision.models import resnet50

class MultiTaskModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        #shared part
        self.resnet50 = resnet50()

        #task specific stuff
        self.tasks = nn.ModuleList()
        self.tasks.add_module('depth', Depth())
        self.tasks.add_module('denseflow', Denseflow())
        #...

    def forward(self, tasktag, ...):
        #shared part
        resnet_output = self.resnet50(...)

        #task specific parts
        if tasktag == 'depth':
            return self.tasks.depth(resnet_output)
        elif tasktag == 'denseflow':
            return self.tasks.denseflow(resnet_output)
        #...
```

Comment: Yes but here you are creating specific weights for a specific task no ?, what i want is to have all model weights reunite into one weight file, so each time i train the model for a specific task its just a sort of finetuning the whole weight

Comment: This class `MultiTaskModel` will create only one model (i.e. one weight file), but you really have to check the accurancy of each task after finetuning for one task if it is still acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Just for an idea you may check the [Detectron2](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) project and in particular how the models are [joined in](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/tutorials/models.html).

Chances are that some ideas they used you may use also.

Fusing the models together means defining the inputs and the outputs for the main model (containing submodels).